# PHP OOP : Fluent interface and tree graphs

Tags: php, oop, tree, fluent-interface

I'm trying to create a **fluent interface for tree objects**.

Here's a simplified example of what I currently do :

```
<?php
class node {
    private $childs = array();
    private $parent;

    public function __construct($parent = null) {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function addChild($child) {
        $this->childs[] = $child;
        return $this;
    }

    public function createChild() {
        return $this->addChild(new node($this));
    }

    public function setFoo() {
        /* do something */
        return $this;
    }
}

$root = new node();

$root   ->addChild((new node($root))
            ->setFoo()
        )->addChild((new node($root))
            ->setFoo()
        );
?>
```

I would like to reduce the part where I create the tree.
What I want to do is something like this :

```
$root->createChild()->setFoo();
$root->createChild()->setFoo();
```

**in one line**. And without having to explicitly create new nodes instances (like I did in the first code with `new` operators).

My goal is to be able to create any tree of any order, and its nodes of any degree without having to put a semi-colon in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding a createChild function I think you should change your constructor and addChild functions to consistently establish the parent / child relationship in the data. Once you've done that the addChild function and the constructor can be used to do what you described without a createChild function. Right now your constructor allow cross-linking between different trees and branches in the trees so it's something that will probably need to change anyway.

```
class node {
    private $childs = array();
    private $parent;

    public function __construct(node $parent = null) {
        if(!is_null($parent)) {
            $parent->addChild($this);
        }
    }

    public function addChild(node $child) {
        $this->childs[] = $child;
        $child->parent = $this;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFoo() {
        /* do something */
        return $this;
    }
}
```

With this you can chain new objects into a tree:

```
$tree = (new node())->addChild(new node())
                    ->addChild((new node())->setFoo())
                    ->addChild((new node())->addChild(new node())
                                           ->addChild(new node())
                                           ->setFoo()
                    );
```

Trying to use a createChild function is a catch-22 situation where sometimes you need the parent and sometimes you need the child. You can solve it using a return object that contains both but I think it's a situation that is better avoided. If you don't like the "(new node())" syntax, a static function might be the way to go:

```
public static function create(node $parent = null) {
    return new node($parent);
}
```

Which might be a little prettier depending on your tastes:

```
$tree = node::create()->addChild(node::create())
                      ->addChild(node::create()->setFoo())
                      ->addChild(node::create()->addChild(new node())
                                               ->addChild(new node())
                                               ->setFoo()
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this methods to create as child as you can.

```
public function createManyChild($nbrOfChild) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $nbrOfChild; $i++){
        $this->addChild(new node($this));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And use the code like this.

```
$root = new node();
$root->createManyChild(3)->setFoo();
```